# How can I access the inner THREE components within web-ifc-viewer?

Tags: three.js, ifc

I'm trying to get access to inner THREE components to be able to change camera positions, add items to the scene, etc. How can I get access to these internal mechanics of THREE from this module? web-ifc-viewer: https://github.com/IFCjs/web-ifc-viewer

Comment: I found the documentation kind of lacking. Have you tried inspecting the object with `console.log(viewer)` to see what’s available inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ifcViewer.context` to get the scene objects from Three.js.
Some other useful properties/ methods

- ifcViewer.context.getScene()
- ifcViewer.context.items

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: This is perfect! I was able to get the scene and camera. However, when I get the camera from the viewer and try to set the position manually to where I need, it doesn't work. I'm assuming there is some loop that's over riding the values. What's the best way to set values on these context items (e.g. scene, camera, orbit controls, etc.) programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Before changing your camera position, you need to disable cameraControls

```
viewer.context.ifcCamera.cameraControls.enabled = false;
```